# How to receive a file after drag and drop

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm trying to build a web application that allows users to drag and drop a file from their desktop (like justbeamit.com) to an "icon" that represents another user, and so that the different user could receive it on the other side. I see that this is possible using the dropzone.js feature, but I want to know is how it's possible to link this with the receiving function so that the other user could download it simply after receiving a notification. I know it sounds complicated, but wish you guys could do good on me by providing knowledge on how to link the drag and drop functionality with a function that allows the other user to receive and download the file. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MVC framework you can get the file from controller as `body.request.body.dataParts.get`